# Latex paint specs on vegetables in garden

Tags: plant-health, tomatoes, peppers, pesticide

I have extensively searched the internet and looked at related questions on here, but I can't find specific information.

Our landlord spray painted the garage with a paint gun and latex paint 2 days ago. Our garden bags were about 30 feet away, but still we noticed yesterday that tiny specs of latex paint are all over our tomatoes, peppers, catnip, basil. If we clean off the paint will they be safe to eat and can?

I have been cleaning them with vinegar and eater mixture before this. If they're still safe to eat how should I clean them?

I feel so depressed. I put so much time and money into this all organic garden and now if the fruit isn't ruined, it still isn't organic anymore.

Also we did move the garden. My boyfriend knew he was "spray painting", but it was communicated to me as "painting" and he thought it was far enough away.

Comment: I'm sorry your garden was contaminated :-(